# Azure SQL Database Management Portal - default column value

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

In the Azure SQL Database Management portal I was trying to add a new column to an existing table that contains rows.

[image: New column]

I added the default value - 0 - thinking that it would add the default to existing rows and therefore setting the column to 'Is Required' (not nullable) would be OK. However, when I tried to save, I got the error:

> ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or
>   have a DEFAULT definition specified, or ...

I could however execute the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Sales
ADD Purchase int NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PurchaseDefault DEFAULT 0
```

When I looked at the table again in azure, I saw that the Default value had ((0))

[image]

So, on the next column that I had to add I tried putting the default in double brackets `((0))`, but that did not work either.

So, I went to SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on my dev machine. Here I can add a new column with 0 in the 'Default Value Or Binding' option. This worked. Interestingly, when I went back the 0 was now ((0)).

So, my questions are:-

1. How is the Default Value column in Azure different from adding a default constraint?
2. Why is this OK in SQL Server 2012, but not Azure?
3. What are the (()) about? I tried googling for various combinations of 'double brackets/braces default constraints', but came up empty.

Comment: I'm new to sql azure and have encountered the exact same problem using the web gui. Anyone with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you met with were correct. I'm not a DBA but let me try to explain something I know for now.

1. If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to specify default value, it will be wrapped by brackets automatically. If your default value is a static value, for example zero, it will be `((0))`, if it's some calculation value for example the current date/time, it will be `(GETDATE())`. But I'm not pretty sure why it must be wrapped by (double) brackets
2. I guess there are some existing records in your SQL Azure. Your understanding of `... it would add the default to existing rows ...` is not correct. Default value will NOT affect existing records. It will just set the value to default if you don't specify explicitly. This is the reason why your got error when you applied your changes in SQL Azure. I think you need to run a script to set the default value to this columns for all existing records then apply this change. Something like `UPDATE [Your_Table] SET [Purchase] = 0 WHERE [Purchase] IS NULL`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The default constraint works fine when I use T-SQL Alter Table syntax as per the SQL in my question. What is the difference between the default constraint and a default value for the column?

Comment: Sorry I've never used default constraint. maybe someone else can help you. ;)

Comment: ShaunXu in point #2 you said "Default value will NOT affect existing records." This is not true. As @acarlon said in his question it was possible to execute an 'alter table...not null...default 0' and it does update all existing records to the default value.  This is standard behavior for all recent Sql Server versions, including SQL Azure.

Comment: Kurt, sorry I'm not agree with you. If you have a table with a column that allows NULL and with records this value was NULL, when you run command to add default value, all new records will have the default value but existing records will NOT set the default value even though it's NULL. Acarlon's script created a new column and set its default value, which will affect all new records. Please correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you? This SQL proves what I'm trying to state: `CREATE TABLE tbl (foo bit NULL); INSERT INTO tbl (foo) values (1); ALTER TABLE tbl ADD bar int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT barDefault DEFAULT 0; select * from tbl` It's adding a NOT NULL column w/ a default value to a table w/ existing rows. The script works and all existing rows will now have the default value (0) for the new 'bar' column.  That's what the OP is trying to accomplish in Azure - adding a Purchase column that is not null w/ default value. This works with tsql, but not through the Azure interface, for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I got your point Kurt. Sorry I think I misunderstood you. Yes if you add a new column that works. What I said is if you already have column `bar` and wants to add default value, existing records will not have the default value.